Elegant Proof of Snake Lemma
I'm considering the following diagram
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
&&&&0&&0&&\\
&&&&\downarrow& &\downarrow& &\\
 & &&  & \text{ker }\beta & \stackrel{\varepsilon_*}\longrightarrow & \text{ker }\gamma & & \\
 &&& & \downarrow\scriptstyle{\psi_1} &\Sigma_1 & \downarrow\scriptstyle{\varphi_1} & & \\
 &  & A & \stackrel{\mu}{\longrightarrow} & B & \stackrel{\varepsilon}{\longrightarrow} & C & \longrightarrow & 0 \\
&  & \downarrow\scriptstyle{\alpha} &\Sigma_3 & \downarrow\scriptstyle{\beta} &\Sigma_2 & \downarrow\scriptstyle{\gamma} & & \\
0 & \longrightarrow & A' & \stackrel{\mu'}{\longrightarrow} & B' & \stackrel{\varepsilon'}{\longrightarrow} & C' & & \\
& &\downarrow\scriptstyle{\psi_2}&\Sigma_4&\downarrow\scriptstyle{\varphi_2}&&&&\\
  & &  \text{coker }\alpha & \stackrel{\mu_*'}\longrightarrow & \text{coker }\beta & &&&\\
& &\downarrow&&\downarrow&&&&\\
&&0&&0&&&&
\end{array}
with all sequence exact. My goal is to prove that

(i) there is a "connecting homomorphism"
$\omega:\ker\gamma\rightarrow\text{coker}\ \alpha$ such that the following
sequence is exact:
$$\ker\alpha\stackrel{\mu_*}\longrightarrow\ker\beta\stackrel{\varepsilon_*}\longrightarrow\ker\gamma\stackrel{\omega}\longrightarrow\text{coker}\ \alpha\stackrel{\mu_*'}\longrightarrow\text{coker}\ \beta\stackrel{\varepsilon_*'}\longrightarrow\text{coker}\ \gamma;$$
(ii) if $\mu$ is monomorphic, so is $\mu_*$; if $\varepsilon'$ is
epimorphic, so is $\varepsilon_*'$.

By a repeated application of Lemma Ⅲ.3.1 in Hilton and Stammbach's A Course in Homological Algebra (Second Edition), I can easily obtain that
$$\text{Im}\ \Sigma_1\cong\text{Ker}\ \Sigma_2\cong\text{Im}\ \Sigma_3\cong\text{Ker}\ \Sigma_4.$$
Since $\varphi_1$ is injective, we have $\text{im}\ \varphi_1\varepsilon_*=\text{im}\ \varepsilon_*$. Then
$$\text{Im}\ \Sigma_1=(\text{im}\ \varphi_1\cap\text{im}\ \varepsilon)/\text{im}\ \varphi_1\varepsilon_*\cong(C\cap\ker\gamma)/\text{im}\ \varepsilon_*=\ker\gamma/\text{im}\ \varepsilon_*=\text{coker}\ \varepsilon_*.$$
Now I have difficulty verifying $\text{Ker}\ \Sigma_4\cong\ker\mu_*'$. Since $\psi_2$ is surjective and $\mu'$ is injective, we have and $\ker\mu'=0$. It then follows that
$$\text{Ker}\ \Sigma_4=\ker\mu_*'\psi_2/(\ker\mu'+\ker\psi_2)=\ker\mu_*'\psi_2/\ker\psi_2.$$
So how to show that $\ker\mu_*'\psi_2/\ker\psi_2\cong\ker\mu_*'$, or is there anything wrong with the above process?
Through the above results, I conclude that $\ker\mu_*'\cong\text{coker}\ \varepsilon_*$. An then how can I achieve my initial goal?

What do you mean when you write $\text{Im}\ \Sigma_1$ and such? You also write things like $\text{ker} {\mu'_} {\psi}2=\text{ker}{\mu'}$, which don't make much sense, since these are maps from two different objects.

It's from Hilton and Stammbach's book. For the following commutative square of $\Lambda$-modules,\begin{array}{ccc}A'&\stackrel{\alpha}\longrightarrow&A\ \downarrow\scriptstyle{\psi}&\Sigma&\downarrow\scriptstyle{\varphi}\ B'&\stackrel{\beta}\longrightarrow&B,\end{array} we write $$\text{Im}\ \Sigma=\text{im}\ \varphi\cap\text{im}\ \beta/\text{im}\ \varphi\alpha,\ \ \ \text{Ker}\ \Sigma=\ker\varphi\alpha/(\ker\alpha+\ker\psi).$$ As for $\ker\mu_'\psi_2=\ker\mu_'$, I seem to have made a mistake. @Sergey Guminov

I edited my question. Do you have any idea to show $\ker\mu_'\psi_2/\ker\psi_2\cong\ker\mu_'$? @Sergey Guminov

What do you want? We could just reprove Snake Lemma for you or point you to a classic proof. See Mac Lane 's proof in "Categories for the Working Mathematician" for a general proof valid in any Abelian category

I understand the classic proof, but Hilton and Stammbach's A Course in Homological Algebra states that there is an elegant proof by this method. @FShrike
